# How to log all process names that connect to the internet?

Tags: log, network-monitoring

I found a virus in Windows 10 today, or at least debris of it and want to make sure Ubuntu is not similarly compromised. How can I log all process names that (try to) make an outgoing internet connection, while using Ubuntu normally?

Comment: What virus is it? It is unlikley to infect stock Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `nethogs` tool to monitor network traffic by process. It shows the process name, PID, user as which it runs, network device it uses and how much it is sending and receiving.

Install it using `sudo apt install nethogs`.

Then you can start monitoring processes interactively using `sudo nethogs`.